# How to calculate a logical curve along a set of values?

Tags: c#, math, curve-fitting

I am trying to take a float value, with an arbitrary minimum and maximum possible value, and convert it to a linear scale, for representation on a bar-shaped indicator. The problem is, I can't just lerp it between the minimum and maximum, because the maximum value will always be dramatically higher than the minimum value. I have an array of arbitrary values that I want to act as intermediate points between the minimum and maximum. Now I just need to calculate a logical best-fit curve through the points. Each value is always larger than the last, and the rate of increase in value accelerates the further up you go, but there is no simple formula for calculating this rate of acceleration.

Here's an example of the values that may be used:

6.0, 13.5, 30.0, 75.0, 375.0

where 6 is the minimum, and 375 is the maximum.
If x is exactly one of these values, I would want a simple value depending on how many total values there are, I.E 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1. The issue is calculating the in-between values.

How would I go about achieving this? I apologize if a question like this has already been asked, as it feels like a common problem, although I didn't know what to search for. If this has already been answered before, please just point me in the right direction.

Comment: This seems like more of a math question than a programming one.

Comment: Apart from this this question is by far too broad, in particular if you don´t show what you´ve tried already.

Comment: @itsme86 Hm, I suppose it is, but I need to write a function to perform this calculation, and I figured posting here would be more likely to get a helpful answer.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I haven't tried anything already, as I do not know where to start, I could just lerp between each value, but that doesn't result in a curve, and as such looks weird for some values.

Comment: This seems like a typical problem for logarithmic functions.  It sounds like you want to accumulate on the log of your value.

Comment: @AlexanderToptygin While normally I would, I am not sure how to make that work with my arbitrary values.

Comment: If a curve might be y(x) = k^(ax+b), take logs of both sides and you have a linear relation. As pointed out tho, this is maths not programming.

Comment: @mrblewog Yeah, I suppose that looks like that would work. Feel free to post that as an answer. Sorry for troubling you all with this surprisingly easy issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not, as framed, a programming problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reposting my comment as an answer, as requested.

If a curve might be y(x) = k^(ax+b), take logs of both sides and you have a linear relation. As pointed out tho, this is maths not programming.

I’d pick k = 2, e or 10 for easier implementation;  a & b you work out from data.